# How to initialise reduce and use accumulator in Julia

Tags: julia

It works without initial value:

`reduce(+, [2 3 4])`

Tried multiple ways to provide initial value - nothing works

```
reduce(+, [2 3 4], 1)
reduce(+, 1, [2 3 4])
```

Also seems like reduce could be used only with 2 argument operator. What function should be used to reduce collection with custom functions that accept current value and accumulator? Something like code below?

```
reduce((accumulator, value) -> push!(accumulator, value^2), [1, 2, 3], [])
# => [1, 4, 9]
```

This example could be implemented as `map(x -> x^2, [1, 2, 3])` but I would like to know how to implement it as reduce with accumulator.

*julia version 1.1.1*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `init` argument to `reduce` is a keyword argument:

```
julia> reduce(+, [2 3 4], init = 1)
10

julia> reduce((accumulator, value) -> push!(accumulator, value^2), [1, 2, 3], init = [])
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 1
 4
 9
```

Comment: Thanks. As for the accumulator - do you know is there a guarantee that it's always will be the first argument and the list will be reduced sequentially from first to last?

Comment: You can use `foldl` if you want to guarantee left associativity of the reduction. The associativity of `reduce` is explicitly not guaranteed.

Comment: Note that `[]` is of type `Vector{Any}` which may impact performance. BTW, why push into an accumulator, rather than use broadcasting?

Comment: @DNF, regarding the accumulator, that seemed more like a "can it be done?" question, rather than a "should it be done?" question. The OP even mentions that he could have used `map` instead for the given example.

Comment: Ok, I just generally like to also address the "should it be done", even if the poster doesn't ask for it.

Comment: @DNF why it's needed - sometimes you need functions that reduce collection to single value, but not in the form of `a someoperator b` instead like `accumulator.somefn(v) for every v in collection`. I used example with `push!` only to demonstrate what I want. If you only need x^2 then of course map or broadcast should be used.